# text inside li element

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

im printing out unordered lists dynamically..something like this

```
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT id, todo FROM todo");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
{
    $todo1 = $row["todo"];
    $todofeed.='

    <ul>
        <li>' . $todo1 . '</li>
    </ul>   

    ';
}
```

I want each li element that is printed out to be a link for some jQuery effect and for that  I need the text inside each li element dynamically i.e. as and when i click on it.Any way around this?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Show us the resulting HTML you'd like to see.

Comment: Wrap your $todo1 with a like <a class="someclass" href="#">$todo1</a> and write a jquery handler for a.someclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a class to your `<ul>` element so that you can access it with Jquery later on:

```
...
$todofeed.='

<ul class="effective">
    <li>' . $todo1 . '</li>
...
```

With Jquery [manipulate the DOM](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) so that your link is added:

```
$('ul.effective li').wrapInner('<a ... />');
```

But you could also [add the click/hover events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) on the `li` elements. Do what suits you better, your question is not really specific, so hopefully this will give you some ideas.

Comment: i will rephrase my question..Im building a todo list application for my site in which on one page I'll display all the titles of todo lists and whenever I click on one of the titles (which is essentially the variable $todo here) i should see all the items of that list sliding down using jQuery.So i need to send over the current value of $todo to maybe an ajax function so that i can extract the items in that list.